# SQLite FTS4 compound MATCH doesn't work with FMDB (iOS, Objective c)

Tags: ios, sqlite, match, fmdb, fts4

I have a simple FTS4 query:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses 
  WHERE addresses MATCH '(PLZ:12* OR Nummer:12*) AND (Ort:Berlin*)'
```

This query works fine with `SQLiteManager` (I get some results), but when I execute this query with FMDB I don't get results (no errors but also no results).

When I use this query with FMDB it works:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses 
  WHERE addresses MATCH 'Ort:Berlin* PLZ:12* OR Nummer:12*'
```

It seems that FMDB has a problem with braces. Is there an alternative for the braces?

Is there a **Bug** in FMDB? I use the simple tokenizer:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses
  USING fts4(id, PLZ, Nummer, Ort, Strasse, tokenize=simple);"];
```

Comment: What are the [compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) of the copy of the SQLite library used by FMDB? In particular, [SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_fts3_parenthesis)?

Comment: That is a good question. So long time ago we compiled that. But I will compile it again with that parameter. That could really be the problem, thanks!

Comment: Yes that solved the problem. Thanks so much!! =)